# Failed to uninstall driver to be installed by INSTALLER1 and upgraded by INSTALLER2

Tags: wix, windows-installer

We have a driver is shipped by two different WiX installers, So I have used same driver components GUID in both the installer source code (.wxs)., shared="yes" and marked  File keypath "Yes".

```
<Component Id="MYDRiverID"
            DiskId ="1"
            Guid="EXXXXXX-XXX-XX"
            Win64="$(var.Is64bit)" Shared="yes">
<File Id="myDriver"
                  Name="driver.sys"
                  Source="Dir\driver.sys"
                  KeyPath="yes"/>
<difx:Driver Legacy="no"
                     Sequence="10"
                     AddRemovePrograms="no"
                     DeleteFiles="yes"
                     PlugAndPlayPrompt="no"
                     ForceInstall="no"/>
```

I am facing while uninstallation If install 1.0.0.0 via **INSTALLER1** and upgrade using **INSTALLER2** 2.0.0.0, newer driver files replaced but when uninstallation If I uninstall using add/remove programs==>>INSTALLER2, it fails to remove driver, when I checked "sc query mydriver" my driver is not uninstalled.

Checked with uninstallation logs/eventvwr did not find any error/failure message.

```
 MSI (s) (F0:74) [19:39:55:832]: Component: _Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win8.XXXXXXX_XXXX_4XXXX3_XXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXX; Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Null;   Client State: Local
 MSI (s) (F0:74) [19:39:55:928]: The file represented by File table key 'MYDriversysWin7' has no eligible binary patches
 MSI (s) (F0:74) [19:39:55:928]: The file represented by File table key 'MYDriversysWin8' has no eligible binary patches
 MSI (s) (F0:74) [19:39:55:928]: The file represented by File table key 'MYDriverinfWin7' has no eligible binary patches
 MSI (s) (F0:74) [19:39:55:928]: The file represented by File table key 'MYDrivercatWin7' has no eligible binary patches
 MSI (s) (F0:74) [19:39:55:928]: The file represented by File table key 'MYDriverinfWin8' has no eligible binary patches
 MSI (s) (F0:74) [19:39:55:928]: The file represented by File table key 'MYDrivercatWin8' has no eligible binary patches
 DIFXAPP: INFO: 'Component' is '_Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win7.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX'
 DIFXAPP: INFO: This is a no-op custom action for component _Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win7.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX. The NoOp_{XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX} property has been set to TRUE.
 DIFXAPP: INFO: 'Component' is '_Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win8.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX'
 DIFXAPP: INFO: This is a no-op custom action for component _Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win8.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX. The NoOp_{MYDRIVER_COMPONENT_GUID} property has been set to TRUE.
 MSI (s) (F0:74) [19:39:56:068]: Executing op: RegOpenKey(Root=-2147483646,Key=SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MYDriver,,BinaryType=1,,)
 DIFXAPP: INFO: 'Component' is '_Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win7.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX'
 DIFXAPP: INFO: This is a no-op for component _Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win7.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX. The NoOp_{XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX} property has been set to TRUE.
 DIFXAPP: INFO: Skipping cleanup for component _Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win7.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX, since it is a no-op.
 DIFXAPP: INFO: 'Component' is '_Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win8.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX'
 DIFXAPP: INFO: This is a no-op for component _Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win8.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX. The NoOp_{MYDRIVER_COMPONENT_GUID} property has been set to TRUE.
 DIFXAPP: INFO: Skipping cleanup for component _Driver_MYDriver.sys_Win8.XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX, since it is a no-op.
 Property(S): DRIVER_MYPRODUCT_COMPONENT_DIR_WIN7 = C:\Program Files\Common Files\XXXXX\Win7\
```

I collected these logs driver on Windows 8.

Added one user mode service to verify it successfully installed/upgraded/uninstalled, I am not getting why it is failing for driver.

Any help would really helpful.

Comment: Have you tested properly on a clean virtual? The shared attribute is for interoperability with non-MSI installers - its only use in MSI is to check if there are legacy installers with a reference to the resource in question preventing its uninstall. Often you accidentally increment the shared flag during testing (by changing the component key at some point - for example), and then your MSI never uninstalls the component afterwards since the legacy shared flag is never 0 - like it should be. Maybe try on a clean virtual to be sure (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs).

Comment: [Cleaning Up Your Shared DLLs Registry References for MSIs](https://blogs.flexera.com/installtalk/2010/11/cleaning-up-your-shared-dlls-registry-references-for-msis/) (untested by me). [And some further MSDN suggestions for stranded components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You should post the entire log. The MSI component state needs checking in the log, together with any other info that might relate to the driver uninstall becoming a no-op.

Comment: Posted possible maximum logs. @SteinÅsmul I have tested on clean VM and also verified with and without reboot.

Comment: Did you check the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs registry key? What are the ref-counts there?

Comment: And the 32-bit key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs

Comment: Why did you set the shared attribute? That changes shared behavior, so I'd turn it off in everything, Installer1 and Installer2 and test on a completely fresh (virtual)  machine.

Comment: Thanks Phil and Stein, Actual issue was INSTALLER1 installing driver using CutomActionTAG and INSTALLER2 installing using difx tag. so i have written custom action for INSTALLER 2. also removed SHARED

Comment: Does UpgradeCode must be same in both installers?

Comment: The `UpgradeCode` should in general be the same for products that are related - for example different versions of the same application (versions 1, 2, 3 etc...), or even different language versions. It allows you to identify "families of setups" and you can define major upgrades and detect existing instances via this `UpgradeCode`. There is a lot to this, but I keep `UpgradeCodes` stable between setups unless I want them to be able to install side-by-side. Then I give them different `UpgradeCodes`.

Comment: Thanks Stein, finally I succeeded, one more question is when I uninstall using ADD/REMOVE=> INSTALLER2 and my components(service and driver) still exists. When I uninstall twice using INSTALLER2 uninstall, **INSTALLER1** uninstall, it cleans completely. is this because of reference count? Is this expected behavior. No **SHARED** flag specififed.